# Execute code after script abort on CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I try to execute some final code after my script got aborted in PHP. So let's say I have this PHP script:

```
while(true) {
    echo 'loop';
    sleep(1);
}
```

if I execute the script with `$ php script.php` it run's till the given execution time.

Now I like to execute some final code after the script has been aborted. So if I

- hit `Ctrl+C`
- the execution time is over

Is there even a possibility to do some clean up in those cases?

I tried it with [`pcntl_signal`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) but with no luck. Also with [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) but this get only called if the script ends successfully.

**UPDATE**

I found out (thx to rch's link) that I somehow can "catch" the events with:

```
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, $restartMyself); // kill
pcntl_signal(SIGHUP,  $restartMyself); // kill -s HUP or kill -1
pcntl_signal(SIGINT,  $restartMyself); // Ctrl-C
```

But if I extend my code with

```
$cleanUp = function() {
    echo 'clean up';
    exit;
};

pcntl_signal(SIGINT, $cleanUp);
```

the  script keeps executing but does not respect the code in `$cleanUp` closure if I hit `Ctrl+C`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function [`pcntl_signal()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) is the answer for the situation when the script is interrupted using `Ctrl-C` (and by other signals). You have to pay attention to the documentation. It says:

> You must use the `declare()` statement to specify the locations in your program where callbacks are allowed to occur for the signal handler to function properly.

The `declare()` statement, amongst other things, installs a callback function that handles the dispatching of the signals received since its last call, by calling the function [`pcntl_signal_dispatch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal-dispatch.php) which in turn calls the signal handlers you installed.

Alternatively, you can call the function [`pcntl_signal_dispatch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal-dispatch.php) yourself when you consider it's appropriate for the flow of your code (and don't use `declare(ticks=1)` at all).

This is an example program that uses `declare(ticks=1)`:

```
declare(ticks=1);

// Install the signal handlers
pcntl_signal(SIGHUP,  'handleSigHup');
pcntl_signal(SIGINT,  'handleSigInt');
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'handleSigTerm');


while(true) {
    echo 'loop';
    sleep(1);
}

// Reset the signal handlers
pcntl_signal(SIGHUP,  SIG_DFL);
pcntl_signal(SIGINT,  SIG_DFL);
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, SIG_DFL);



/**
 * SIGHUP: the controlling pseudo or virtual terminal has been closed
 */
function handleSigHup()
{
    echo("Caught SIGHUP, terminating.\n");
    exit(1);
}

/**
 * SIGINT: the user wishes to interrupt the process; this is typically initiated by pressing Control-C
 *
 * It should be noted that SIGINT is nearly identical to SIGTERM.
 */
function handleSigInt()
{
    echo("Caught SIGINT, terminating.\n");
    exit(1);
}

/**
 * SIGTERM: request process termination
 *
 * The SIGTERM signal is a generic signal used to cause program termination.
 * It is the normal way to politely ask a program to terminate.
 * The shell command kill generates SIGTERM by default.
 */
function handleSigTerm()
{
    echo("Caught SIGTERM, terminating.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thx! Works like a charm. Can you tell me why exactly I have to reset the signal handlers? I think that was the thing I missed in my approach with pcntl_signal together with `ticks = 1`...

Comment: I don't know if resetting the signal handlers does the job. I put them there from habit, it's a good coding practice to close the open files, destruct the constructed objects, release the allocated resources a.s.o. If you don't want to `exit()` immediately but want to do additional processing it's recommended to set a flag in the signal handler and check it in the main program loop and proceed accordingly (or use `pcntl_signal_dispatch()` instead of `declare(ticks=1)`. You can read more about [termination signals](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html).

Comment: Thx again for the answer and the interesting link. So if I like to use the `pcntl_signal_dispatch` instead of `ticks = 1` where do I have to call it? Somewhere in my loop? Then the scripts gets executed up to the dispatch call I guess and then calls the callback defined by `pcntl_signal` function. right?

Comment: `PHP` installs handlers for signals and they put the received signals in a queue. The function `pcntl_signal_dispatch()` picks the signals from the queue and invokes the handlers you provided for them using `pcntl_signal()`. It runs when you call it (once every loop or whenever it fits your code better). The statement `declare(ticks=1)` installs a [`tick function`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks) that calls `pcntl_signal_dispatch()`. Due to `ticks=1` it runs more often and the script is more responsive (but it runs slightly slowly).

Answer (score 0):

This may have some really useful information, it looks like they're utilizing the same things you've attempted but seemingly with positive results? Perhaps there's something here you haven't attempted or maybe missed.

[Automatically Restart PHP Script on Exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798438/automatically-restart-php-script-on-exit)

Answer (score 0):

Check this: connection_aborted()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php

Here's an example of how to use it to achieve what you want:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php#111167