# Automatic Simple HTML DOM with Check Point

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, checkpoint, checkpointing

Good evening,

I wanted to ask a question that I'm not sure it can be done.
I have a scraping program made with Simple HTML DOM.

The program extracts data from various websites.

So my question is:

Is it possible to automate the program to be able to auto restart if it fails?

And I go further ...

I would restart the program from a specific point, for example:

```
process 1 -- save category1 data from web in BBDD table1

checkpoint

process 2 -- save category2 data from web in BBDD table2
```

if the program fails to process 2, I would like to restart working from checkpoint.

If not possible, you tell me and delete the question. No problem.

Many thanks.

Comment: I answered myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798438/automatically-restart-php-script-on-exit

Comment: agh no, this is for unix...i need same for windows -_-, any idea?