# Restart php / curl script after execution

Tags: php, curl, restart

I have a curl request on an api with pagination and now I'd like to execute my php script several times so that I don't have to start it manually with a different pagenumber

```
$endpoint = 'https://xxx.weclapp.com/webapp/api/v1/';
$api_token = 'xxx';
$articlePerPage = 100;
$currentPage = 1;
$amountOfArticles = "different curl get request (approx 1100)"
$amountOfPages = ceil($amountOfArticles / $articlePerPage);
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$header[] = 'AuthenticationToken:'.$api_token;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$endpoint.'article/?page='.$currentPage.'&pageSize='.$articlePerPage);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$JSON = curl_exec($curl);
$result = json_decode($JSON);
```

I tried to put it in a while loop

```
while ($currentPage <= $amountOfPages) : ...; endwhile;
```

but unfortunately there are to much products respectively it takes to long so my server won't finish all these calls and I get a 504

At the moment I start this script manually 12 times each time with a different $currentPage number. My idea is to let the server finish the script, then restart it with $currentPage++ but I don't have any clue how to do that.

I've read the solution on this topic [9798438](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798438/automatically-restart-php-script-on-exit) with the bin/bash script but then I can't change my $currentPage variable

Does anyone has any idea how I could manage what I'm trying to do?

Thank you very much, I'd appreciate any help

Alex

Comment: i guess your 504 loop was completely unoptimized? you probably did NOT use compression, did NOT re-use tcp connections, did NOT re-use curl handles, and did NOT use curl_multi/multiprocessing... ?

Comment: Thank you, I will look into your suggestions